# How to search data with ng-click in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to search data with `ng-click` function in angularJS, but when I try this code, it doesn't work.

First my button code:

```
<button id="veg" ng-click="myFilter = {type: 1}" title="veg">
```

My data display code:

```
<div class="side-body padding-top fade in  tab-pane"  id="<?php echo $tt3->id; ?>">
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-if='r.pro_category == <?php echo $tt3->id; ?>'
             ng-repeat = "r in groups | filter : searchGroups | filter:myFilter">
            <div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div>
                        <img src="../@{{r.image }}" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <div>@{{r.pro_name }}</div>
                        <div>@{{r.price}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

My script code:

```
var GroupsApp = angular.module('GroupsApp',[]);
GroupsApp.controller('GroupsController', function ($scope, GroupsService) {

    getGroups();

    function getGroups() {
        GroupsService.getGroups()
            .success(function (grps) {
                $scope.groups = grps;


                 return (val.type != 2);
                console.log($scope.groups);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load Product data: ' + error.message;
                console.log($scope.status);
            });
    }
});

var url = window.location.pathname;
var productid = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

GroupsApp.factory('GroupsService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var GroupsService = {};

    GroupsService.getGroups = function () {
        return $http.get('../showproduct/'+productid);
    };
    return GroupsService;
}]);
```

When I run above code it doesn't show anything.

Comment: your code is of angularJs type, and you tagged into Angular2. make correction please

Comment: Please explain *it doesn't show anything*

Comment: Means data shows perfecty in normal. Now i have some flag or type for product. For that i have define button. so when i add ng-click in button as mention in my code it doesn't filter data...filter like veg or non-veg @PankajParkar

Comment: ok thanks @PardeepJain can you help me  to slove my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button href="#" id="veg" ng-click="myFilter = {active: 1}" title="All Menu Items"  class="bbb1 btn btn-info btn-lg "  >
```